# Customizing renderer for MapImageLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Using arcgis 4.2 trying to load a custom fillrenderer fails to produce any results on my map, if I try to load the layer straight from the service it will load but setting my own renderer fails to yield any results.

`var statesRenderer = new SimpleFillSymbol({
                                            color: [ 51,51, 204, 0.9 ],
                                            style: "solid",
                                            outline: {                                                 color: "white",
                                                    width: 1
                                                  }
                                                });
         var resultsLabelLayer = new MapImageLayer({
                  url: url,
                   sublayers: [{
                                id: 1,
                                visible: true,
                                renderer: statesRenderer
                              }]
           });`

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: that is the strange part, I am not getting any errors so I am not even sure what to debug to fix this issue

Comment: Can you post the entirety of your code?

Comment: Code is already added above